# Property "id" does not exist on type "MyProps" (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was practicing with typescript and I have a problem, I am trying to pass information from the API to a variable (this is just to have the necessary information), but I have this error message:: "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'MyProps'" and "Property 'url' does not exist on type 'MyProps'", this is my code.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { CardGif } from "./components/CardGif";
import { Content } from "./components/layout/Content";
import InterfaceImage from './Interfaces/InterfaceImage'

interface MyProps {
  gifs: InterfaceImage[]
}

function App() {

  const handleLoadInformation = async () => {
    const key = 'url';
    const url = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=goku&limit=10&api_key=${key}`;

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const { data } = await response.json();

    const images = data.map((img: MyProps) => {
      return {
        id: img.id,
        url: img.url
      }
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleLoadInformation();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Content>
        <div className="w-[90%] m-auto columns-3">
          <CardGif />
        </div>
      </Content>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my Interface:

```
export default interface InterfaceImage {
   id: number,
   url: string,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error stems from this piece of code:

```typescript
const images = data.map((img: MyProps) => {
  return {
    id: img.id,
    url: img.url
  }
})
```

When you try to get `img.id` and `img.url`, the TypeScript compiler sees that `img` should be of type `MyProps`, which only has one property—`gifs`.

```typescript
interface MyProps {
  gifs: InterfaceImage[] // no `id` or `url` props here
}
```

To fix this error in general, you can add the props to the interface definition:

```typescript
interface MyProps {
  gifs: InterfaceImage[],
  id: number,
  url: string,
}
```

However, considering the `InterfaceImage` interface that you have defined, I assume that what you really need is to change the type annotation in the `.map()` callback:

```typescript
const images = data.map((img: InterfaceImage) => {
  return {
    id: img.id,
    url: img.url
  }
})
```

Comment: Now I understand better, thanks for the explanation.